# access vbscript session variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, vbscript

in a bit of a pickle.

The aim is to remember the date a user picked. Process being:

They select date (e.g march 7th 2014) and click next (page 2).
On the page 2 the date they select becomes a session variable

```
Dim bookStart
bookStart = request.form("start")
'manipulate bookstart for everything else
session("selectedDate") = bookStart
```

The user then decides they want to go back a page (page 1) and select another date instead so they click back. My problem is the session variable i displayed on page 1 is nothing and I don't know why. Here is a snippet in my document.ready and a part of the form(for page 1):

```
if(!$('#selectedDate').val() == null || !$('#selectedDate').val() == ""){
    alert("there's something in here, lets display it: "+$('#selectedDate').val());
}
else if (dateCounter == null){
    var current = new Date();
    dateChange(current, "", 0);
    dateCounter = 0;
}

<input type="hidden" id="selectedDate" value="<%=session("selectedDate")%>">
```

The if statement works that if the value is empty in the hidden input field, load the page with todays date!
Please help!!

Comment: To clarify, on page 2 I did a response.write on the session variable and it did display a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the biggest idiot in the world. Turns out if page 1 is on HTTP and page 2 is HTTPS, you won't be able to access session variables between the 2. So I just make page 1 secure and things just worked!